# Flutter dynamic forms

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Looking for a way to create dynamic forms on flutter.
I need the forms to get the IDs of the fields from firestore and use it to build a form so that instead of adding the form field manually on the code, I just add it to the database and it automatically adds the field to the form.